# Flutter iOS app configuration with different firebase projects shows error GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have 3 different schemes with diffrenet firebase projects thati want to manage using my xcode, I have added all configurations and scripts but at the end i am getting this error

> Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

I tried many solution like adding a temporary file in project directory and also configuring firebase app with options but nothing works.
Below is my script for copying file into direcotry

```
if [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Debug-Production” ] || [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Release-Production” ] || [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Release” ]|| [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Debug” ]; then
cp -r ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/Production/GoogleService-Info.plist   ${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist 
echo "production plist Copied"
elif [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Debug-Beta” ] || [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Release-Beta” ]; then
cp -r ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/Beta/GoogleService-Info.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
elif [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Debug-Test” ] || [ “${CONFIGURATION}” == “Release-Test” ]; then
cp -r ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/Test/GoogleService-Info.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
fi
```

Here is my build phase order
[image: Firebase config section runs my copying script]

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, For working around almost a full day and after trying all solutions i have found one which is not mentioned in any answer.

- Add a proper Googleservice-info.plist in your projet and check copy files and target
- In script change cp to cp -r and while remove filename from the end when you are pasting it. it should be like `${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/`.
- Every time your scripts run it will replace the file but not the rights it has.

I hope it works for you too.